# Eslint is not recognizing key prop from react-table when destructuring. 'error: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator react/jsx-key'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-table

Eslint is giving me the error even though `getHeaderGroupProps()` is supposed to pass the `key` prop when destructuring.

I have this

```
......
<Tr  {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} >
.....
```

And I get the error: `Missing "key" prop for element in iterator react/jsx-key`

But when I add `key={headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps().key}`

```
......
<Tr  {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} key={headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps().key}>
.....
```

The error disappears, but shouldn't be the same since `getHeaderGroupProps` is passing the `key`?

Even when I change the order first `key` then rest of props I get `'key' is specified more than once`

`.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn"
    }
}
```

**Versions:**

```
"react-table": "^7.8.0"
"react": "^18.2.0"
"eslint": "^8.24.0"
```